# SQL function with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database, entities

Is there a way to use SQL functions with the `EntityFieldQuery` class?

What I am trying to do is something similar to the following code:

```
$query_user = new EntityFieldQuery;

$query_user
->entityCondition('entity_type','user')
->fieldCondition('MD5(user+pass)',null,$user_token,'=')
```

The interesting part is the `EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition()` call.
Obviously this it isn't working, otherwise I would not ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The whole point of EntityFieldQuery is that it is SQL-agnostic, so you can switch from MySQL to MongoDB for example, and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to [fieldCondition](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AfieldCondition/7) is expecting to be the field you want to query. So unless you have a field called `MD5(user+pass)` this won't work. You can't query with arbitrary SQL like that.

Read the documentation linked above about how to use the method. This is generally a good place to start when things don't work, to check if you can do what you are trying to do.

From the doc:

> public EntityFieldQuery::fieldCondition($field, $column = NULL, $value = NULL, $operator = NULL, $delta_group = NULL, $language_group = NULL)
>
> $field Either a field name or a field array.

Comment: Stackexchange says to offer a comment with a downvote so here goes: The question is "Is there a way to use SQL functions with the EntityFieldQuery class?", not "how does fieldCondition work?" The poster only wrote code as a model of what s/he would like to do with a similar function. So this response does not answer the question.